Is there any way to avoid confusion when using the word or?
The word or can have, among others, 2 meanings:
Meaning 1: Options of different things

If x^2 - 4 = 0 then x is 2 or -2.
You can mix it with chocolate or cheese.

Meaning 2: Synonyms

If 2x=8 then x is 8/2 or 4.
The solutions are any even numbers or any numbers that can be evenly divided by 2 without remainder.

But sometimes it is not clear without further investigations:

You can find the details from books written by Mark Twain or Samuel Clemens.

Apparently Mark Twain or Samuel Clemens are the same person.
My question is: When we use the word or, is there any way to make its meaning clear at a glance (whether meaning 1 or meaning 2)?

In case of meaning 1, when there is 2 options, using "either A or B" clearly states that it's a choice.

When ambiguity occurs, you generally have to be a bit more verbose:

You can find the details from books written by Mark Twain, also known as Samuel Clemens.

I'd say, however, that there's more expectation of a comma for a use of "or" to mean "in other words". Consider, for example,

But garbanzo beans, or chickpeas, are good for you.

This sentence would look weird without the commas.

Or "Mark Twain, the pen-name of Samuel Clemens".

The synonym sense is often indicated by using various types of punctuation:

You can find details from books written by Mark Twain (or Samuel Clemens).


You can find details from books written by Mark Twain, or Samuel Clemens.

We also often use "AKA" (abbreviation for "also known as") rather than "or", but this is only appropriate for names, not other types of synonyms (e.g. 8/2 and 4).
In the square root example, we would actually says that x is 2 and -2, not *or*. You could also use and when listing book authors, although this could have an alternate interpretation of them as co-authors.
True ambiguity is rare, the context and common sense usually make it clear which meaning is intended.

But from null factor theorem, if AB=0 then A=0 OR B=0. Applying it to x^2-4=0, we have (x-2)(x+2)=0, so x is -2 or 2.

The AB=0 case is different, because the two possibilities are independent. For square roots, we say that every number has two square roots, N and -N.

Analogy: You make smores with graham crackers, chocolate, and marshmallow. But you make a martini with gin or vermouth.
